# First Element in TwoDimensional Array goes to null?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, null

I am using this code to insert the details in to TwoDimensional Array. But while retrieving the data from the array the first element value changes to null.

```
    Cursor consultancy = db.getConsultancy(this);
        if(consultancy!=null)
        {
            consultancy.moveToFirst(); 
            consultancy.moveToNext();  
            consultancynames = new String[(int) db.getConsultancyCount()-1];
            for(int i=0;i<db.getConsultancyCount()-1;i++)
            { 
                consultancynames[i] = consultancy.getString(2);  
                int consultantid = Integer.parseInt(consultancy.getString(consultancy.getColumnIndex(TimeAndExpensesLocalDB.CT_CONSULTANCYID))); 
                Cursor project_namecur = db.getProjectCode(this, consultantid);
                if(project_namecur!=null)
                {
                    project_namecur.moveToFirst();  
                    projectname = new String[(int) db.getConsultancyCount()][project_namecur.getCount()];
                    for(int j=0;j<project_namecur.getCount();j++)
                    {  
                        projectname[i][j] = project_namecur.getString(3);    
                        project_namecur.moveToNext();  
                    } 
                }
                consultancy.moveToNext();
            }  

        }  

        //... Print array  
        for (int i =0; i < consultancynames.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < projectname.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + projectname[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
```

Output

```
       05-25 12:58:22.700: I/System.out(2373):  null null null
       05-25 12:58:22.700: I/System.out(2373):  Other-1 Other-2 Other-3
```

I am not sure what is happening.

Thanks for your help guys..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new array on each iteration of the loop:

```
projectname = new String[(int) db.getConsultancyCount()][project_namecur.getCount()];
```

So on the first iteration you're creating an array and filling in the *first* "row" of the array. On the second iteration you're creating a new array (which will default to having null elements) and filling in the *second* row.

I suspect you need to allocate the "outer" array once *before* the loop, then allocate the "inner" array based on how many project names there are for that consultant:

```
 // Note: more idiomatic names would be consultancyNames and
 // projectNames. It's also unclear why you're subtracting one from the count...
 consultancynames = new String[(int) db.getConsultancyCount() - 1];
 projectnames = new String[consultancynames.length][];
 for (int i = 0;i< consultancenames.length; i++) {
     ...
     projectnames[i] = new String[project_namecur.getCount())];
     ...
 }
```

Then you'll need to change your display code too, e.g. to

```
for (int i =0; i < projectname.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < projectname[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + projectname[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thats fab... You pointed out the mistake.. Thanks a lot man.. Cheersss

Comment: Ya sure i have to wait 10 minutes to mark as answer.. thats what.. here you go

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't do the following:

```
projectname = new String[(int) db.getConsultancyCount()][project_namecur.getCount()];
for(int j=0;j<project_namecur.getCount();j++)
{  
    projectname[i][j] = project_namecur.getString(3);    
    project_namecur.moveToNext();  
}
```

Here's why:

After the first line `projectname` will be an array of arrays.

Since the arrays are object references you have an array of object references.

Since the default value of an object reference is `null`, you'll have an array of `null` elements.

This means you can't do

```
projectname[i][j] = project_namecur.getString(3);
```

since it corresponds to

```
String[] row = projectname[i];
// row == null !
row[j] = project_namecur.getString(3);
```